# Adding singalr Dependency in android gives library dependency error

Tags: c#, android, signalr

I am using with **signalr** on android, after adding dependency from **official microsoft website** 
`compile 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:1.0.0'`

**I am having this error.**

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

Gradle sync successfully. but failed in building.

Note that I have already added these line in my app.gradle file but no success.

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

This is my gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adnanshaukat.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*. jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:design:27.0.1"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

module gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven{
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Kindly help I have been trying for 3 days but no success, Will be very thankful :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The solution I tried and it is working for me after 3 days of struggle.
Download the jar files from here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xcccz4gwjnxuiz8/AAClkwO_6KrbbyMclgD2ae_pa?dl=0
The official dependency from the microsoft website is not working for me.

download **signalr-client-sdk.jar** and **signalr-client-sdk-android.jar** and place them in **app/libs** folder

My updated gradle file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adnanshaukat.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*. jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:design:27.0.1"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `gradle` :

**May be some dependencies can compile with Java 8, not for Android especially. Try to switch that dependencies to older version. I do not know exactly which library you have to downgrade.**

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

**EDIT :**

Change this :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Comment: No success it says "Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process."  

Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

Comment: I have added the lines there but no success, it gives me this error
Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.
After enabling jack option using this. 
'jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }'
this is the error 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: what java version have you installed in your system ? @AdnanShaukat

Comment: the java version is 1.8.0

Comment: can you mention gradle:module file? @AdnanShaukat

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, but I have solved the issue by not using the dependency from the official website but by downloading the jar files from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xcccz4gwjnxuiz8/AAClkwO_6KrbbyMclgD2ae_pa?dl=0